# Killing application user after sometime in db2

Tags: db2

I want kill my application user after 24 hours automatically how it will be possible in db2, please share the script

Comment: By using ideltime I tried

Comment: Workload Manager should help

Comment: You may use a routine scheduled to run regularly (use db2 ATS, for example), which would force such applications based on difference between CURRENT TIMESTAMP and CONNECTION_START_TIME of the `mon_get_connection` function.